# How to save my debugging windows (like the watch) in code::blocks

Tags: debugging, codeblocks

Each time I run the debugger in code::blocks, I have to manually launch the watch window.  Then I have to manually dock it.

I attempted to retain this by going to: view->perspective->save current

but this didn't work.  Any ideas on how to retain my debugger window settings?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 2):

I realized that I need to select my *saved perspective* when I want to see the saved debugging windows.  I guess I've been spoiled by other IDEs that have separate views for debugging and automatically launch them when tracing through the program.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to dig out, but for those intereset there is a work-around to that:
If you go to View->Perspectives tab you should have a perspective named 
"GBD/CDB debugger:Default"

Once you set up all the debugging windows you want, if you save the current perspective with this same exact name, it will automatically be launched when launching debug session.